# ComboBox missing items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm facing a weird problem with `ComboBox`. I would like to represent key combinations in a ComboBox, where every key is on a `Canvas`.

`Binding` works just fine, and after initialization it looks ok, but when I click on it and expand the dropdown list the current selected item will be empty and if I change the selected item repeatly after a while the dropdown items will be empty also.

Of course the Keys collection is not changing after the initialization. I'm using custom style but it also occurs with the default one.

Here is a short gif about the described behaviour:

[image: Example]

I'm using MVVM pattern (MVVM Light) and my VM is the following:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        private ObservableCollection<List<VirtualKeyCode>> _Keys;
        public ObservableCollection<List<VirtualKeyCode>> Keys
        {
            get => _Keys;
            set => Set(() => Keys, ref _Keys, value);
        }
}
```

XAML snippet:

```
<ComboBox MinHeight="42" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="5,0" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Viewbox Width="Auto" Height="40" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform">
                                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Converter={Converters:StringToResourceConverter}}" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Used converter which just works fine in other cases:

```
public class StringToResourceConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? Application.Current.TryFindResource(value.ToString()) : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Keys are defined on Canvas as resource for example the T key is:

```
<Canvas x:Key="VK_T" Width="53" Height="53.531">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradient3646" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="-80,65" EndPoint="-4,65">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#D8D8D8" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#B1B1B1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.2087115 0 0 0.2080024 309.2826 408.16259" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradient3650" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="333,520" EndPoint="356,536">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#656565" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#939393" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.2087115 0 0 0.2080024 282.55261 440.92403" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradient3653" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="339,522" EndPoint="359,538">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#D6D6D6" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#939393" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="-0.2087115 0 0 0.2080024 467.43777 440.92403" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="linearGradient3657" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="529,334" EndPoint="526,321">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#D6D6D6" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#656565" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.2087115 0 0 0.2080024 282.55261 440.92403" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-348.5" Y="-505.59375" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="349.25" Canvas.Top="506.34" Width="51.494" Height="52.044" Fill="#FF656565" RadiusX="4.7705" RadiusY="4.0115" />
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="389.44" Canvas.Top="510.2" Width="11.279" Height="34.564" Fill="#FFD6D6D6" />
        <Path Data="m391.6 513.22 9.0939-2.9715c-0.3613-2.8568-2.3291-3.8457-5.0687-3.9372-3.6454 0.10572-7.2028 0.26014-9.0939 1.3372l5.0687 5.5715z" Fill="{StaticResource linearGradient3657}" />
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="358.35" Canvas.Top="545.4" Width="33.469" Height="12.975" Fill="#FF929292" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" />
        <Path Data="m389.9 542.35 10.805 1.1556 0.0395 10.506c-0.006 2.7094-2.1668 4.2661-4.4011 4.3599l-4.8096-0.0525-5.3234-12.344 3.6895-3.6245z" Fill="{StaticResource linearGradient3653}" />
        <Path Data="m356.76 542.25-7.4845 1.2607-0.0395 10.506c0.006 2.7094 2.1668 4.2661 4.4011 4.3599l4.8096-0.0525 1.6866-12.292-3.3733-3.782z" Fill="{StaticResource linearGradient3650}" />
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="356.02" Canvas.Top="507" Width="36.535" Height="40.245" Fill="#FFF1F1F1" RadiusX="4.7705" RadiusY="4.7543" />
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="356.02" Canvas.Top="507" Width="35.481" Height="40.245" Fill="{StaticResource linearGradient3646}" RadiusX="4.7705" RadiusY="4.7543" />
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="360.15726" Canvas.Top="511.7" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontStyle="normal" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#FF000000">
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="14">T</TextBlock>
        </TextBlock>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="349.25" Canvas.Top="506.34" Width="51.494" Height="52.044" RadiusX="4.7706" RadiusY="4.0115" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeMiterLimit="4" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" StrokeThickness="1.5" />
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Regards, David

Comment: Try to set the `x:Shared` attribute on the `Canvas` resources to `False`.

Comment: Thank you very much it did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `x:Shared` attribute on the `Canvas` resources to `False`:

```
<Canvas x:Key="VK_T" x:Shared="False" ...>
```